# Query for using more than 1 value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to search documents that have certain keywords, for example:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "592779d4e4b027e032c585ec"} , "url" : "http:/test.com/" , "keywords" : [ "pp" , "ww" , "dd" , "f"]}

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "42127741d42142142c585ec"} , "url" : "http:/taa.com/" , "keywords" : [ "qq" , "aa" , "dd" , "e"]}
```

How can I do a query so that when I search "qq+dd" only document B is returned? Right now, it returns both documents.

Thank you

Comment: You might want to take a look at the concept of inverted index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

Comment: You want [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/). i.e `{ "keywords" : { "$all": ["qq","dd"] } }`

Comment: Thank you for your response! How can I use $all in java? I'm not being able to use it.

Comment: I've managed to do it, thank you for the tip!